# Correct implementation of background worker for Azure function app

Tags: .net-core, background-process, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-function-app

What would be the correct way to implement a background worker, on an azure function app, http triggered?
The process won't be in any way a long running one, just 2-3 rest calls (between 0,5 and 3 seconds), but enough to break the overall user experience.

Currently, I am using `Task.Run(async ())`. The same rest calls are used in other use-cases are normally available calls.

Normally I would deal with it by using a `IHostedService`, but it's not available in Azure function apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to have a different trigger. Have your HTTP-triggered function place a queue message in a queue, and have the queue-triggered function execute the background work.

This is the [proper solution for request-extrinsic code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-1-basic-distributed-architecture.html) anyway, even if you aren't using Functions.

Note that your queue messages will be delivered at-least-once, so if your queue-triggered function isn't idempotent, then you'll need to de-duplicate them.

Comment: So I am assuming a simple, context aware fire and forget implementation equivalent with the simplicity of Task.Run ... is not appropriate / recommend for this use case ?

Comment: @Konstantine: I'd say fire-and-forget is not appropriate any time the work needs to be done.